# Browsing sequence of divs using mouse click

Tags: jquery, html, click, cycle

OK so this is what I am trying to do:
I am trying to create simply, sequence of DIVS, arrange all of them inside a main DIV, then - putting all of them in an absolute position. afterwards I am trying to create a really simple Jquery function which will allow clicking on the DIV's and basically browse all of them, one by one till the last one.

here is an example:

```
<div id="slideshow">
     <div> any content here.. </div>
     <div> any content here.. </div>
     <div> any content here.. </div>
     <div> any content here.. </div>
     <div> any content here.. </div>
<div> any content here.. </div>
</div>
```

**Clicking on the first div will cycke through all the dive untill the last one..**

It seems pretty simple but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.
I don't want to use JQuery Cycle Plugin - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ 
since it requires alot of coding and lot's of files to be included.
Just a simple Jquery function which will allow it.

can anyone help? I need 2 things:

1. Cycle through the divs until the end and then stop(no looping)
2. Looping the whole sequence when reaching the last div (still by clicking)

Thanks a lot

Comment: _"Cycle through the divs until the end and then stop by no looping"_, how?

Answer (score 0):

try `each()` method:

```
$('#slideshow').click(function() {
  $('#slideshow div').each(function() {
     // do something here
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi @undefined 
Created a Jsfiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hamergil/dFWPn/6/ 
Can you help editing the each function so that on every click it will show the next div? Thanks!